# Alternate for SELECTEDVALUE

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to create a measure for example Item Text that combines LicenseName and Qty as shown below but without having to add these these columns in the table visual. The Goal is to show all the License Names of an invoice but only formatted as follow:
[image]

code for the column uses SELECTEDVALUE:

`Item Text = SELECTEDVALUE('Invoices'[LicenseName]) & "-" & [Qty] & " Users"`

SELECTEDVALUE seems to work only when LicenseName is added to the table and not otherwise. The other issue is that Qty is subject to RLS, so we can't use calculated columns nor Power query for creating this text.

What we need is just this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's your intention here? From where should *LicenceName* be selected? A slicer?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain further

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: You need to add some way for Power BI to «see» that there are two rows for this Invoice number. Measures won’t cause row expansion in a visual. Why are you getting this result? `SELECTEDVALUE` can’t find a unique value (there are two) and blanks out.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add an index column to your base. Use the Index Column function in Power Query.

This index column will serve as the single primary key, so you can create the concatenation measure.

Measure:

```
Result Item Text = 
VAR CONCAT = 
SELECTEDVALUE(Tabela[Índice]) & SELECTEDVALUE('Tabela'[Invoice Nr])

VAR TEST_CONDICION = 
IF(
  VALUE(CONCAT) > 0,
  SELECTEDVALUE('Tabela'[License Name]) & " - " & 
  SELECTEDVALUE('Tabela'[Quantity]),
  BLANK()
)

RETURN
TEST_CONDICION
```

[image]

[image]

With this measure you can keep only the index column or Invoice Nr in the visual of the table that it will work correctly.